# How does Googlebot crawl pages having cookiepro integration

Tags: seo, googlebot

Google bot is appending the link present in cookiepro banner on my main product-details page and hence giving 404. 
On the webapp the link is going to the proper URL, but I can see a lot of URLS in my Googlebot logs where this link is being appended on existing URL giving 404.
Can I get an Idea how googlebot crawls the cookiepro cookie consent banner?

Comment: Can you tell us more?  I'm not sure anybody here has used Cookipro, but we could help if you gave us more info.   What code does Cookipro put in your pages?  Is it JavaScript or HTML?  What are some examples of the links?  Or just tell us what your site is and we can take a look ourselves.

Comment: The website is www.pens.com/ie. 
The link is being appended only on the product-details pages link https://www.pens.com/ie/p/rainbow-alpha-soft-touch-pen-with-stylus/prd-zpejmjhh/ where we have a trailing slash at end of it

Comment: Which link is getting appended to the URL?  Is it the privacy policy URL?

Comment: Are you using Google Tag Manager to insert cookie pro into the page?

Comment: Yes, the url "/s/privacy-policy" is getting appended to the URL

Comment: No, Google tag manager is not used. We have added the Cookiepro javascript script to add cookie pro into the page..

Comment: I don't see the JavaScript in the page.  The only CookiePro related line in the page source is `window.np.clientData.cookieproCdn = "https://cookie-cdn.cookiepro.com/langswitch/21bce115-1d46-4eb5-be66-299160e0df08.js";`   Is it getting include from some other bit of JavaScript?

Comment: The banner HTML and all that stuff is defined in cookiepro(i.e. at their site) and its cdn script is loaded when the page loads. Thats all.

Comment: So the link to the privacy policy is created at the Cookie Pro site?   Can you share more about that like a screen shot of how it is entered?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102125/discussion-between-najiba-and-stephen-ostermiller).